# Validate KML geometries in python

Tags: python, geometry, kml, data-validation

I have a CSV file where in a column there are some KML geometries.
These geometries can be points, lines, polygons etc. I would like to validate them and check if they are correctly written.

I'm reading the CSV with Pandas

```
import pandas as pd
csv = read_csv('file.csv')

#Let's take into account just the first location
coordinates = csv.['location'].loc[0]
```

coordinates would be:

```
<Point><coordinates>2.34880,48.85341</coordinates></Point>
```

I tried to proceed with [fastKML](https://fastkml.readthedocs.io/), but it searches for a complete KML file to check and not just the string I got.

So I'm wondering, is there any possibility to validate directly the sting?

---

Edit: With the tip from @user2856 I manage to check the geometry.

i.e.:

```
kml_start="<kml xmlns='http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2'><Placemark><name>Simple placemark</name><description>Test.</description>'"
kml_end = "</Placemark></kml>"
kml_test = kml_start+str(coordinates)+kml_end

try:
    k = kml.KML()
    k.from_string(kml_test)
    print("geometry")
except:
    errors +=1
    print("Error, no Geometry")
```

Comment: Perhaps wrap it into a complete KML string for a [simple placemark](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#placemarks), then parse it with fastkml `from_string`

Comment: @user2856, thank you! Yep, with your tip it works.

Comment: A quick web search returned this Python KML library that claimss to validate KML files.  https://pythonhosted.org/pykml/.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps wrap it into a complete KML string for a simple [placemark](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kml_tut#placemarks), then parse it with fastkml `from_string`:

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd
csv = read_csv('file.csv')

#Let's take into account just the first location
coordinates = csv.['location'].loc[0] 

kml_template = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">
  <Placemark>
    <name></name>
    <description></description>
    {}
  </Placemark>
</kml>
"""

k = kml.KML()
k.from_string(kml_template.format(coordinates))
```